# how to show longitude, latitude in label of this same code

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mapkitannotation

//ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addresslbl;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

//Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D updateLocation;
    NSString *strAddress;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController
#define AzaveaCoordinate CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.167391, 73.247686)

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(AzaveaCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.010, 0.010)) animated:YES];


    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude longitude:mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude];
    [self geocode:location];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = currentLocation.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation.coordinate,1500,1500);
    [self.mapView setRegion: region animated:true];
    [self geocode:currentLocation];
}

  -(void)geocode:(CLLocation *)location

{
   // geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [geocoder cancelGeocode];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *data, NSError *error)
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [data lastObject];

            NSDictionary * addressDict = placemark.addressDictionary;

            NSArray * addressList = addressDict[@"FormattedAddressLines"];

         NSString * address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",addressList[0],addressList[1],addressList[2]];
         NSLog(@" Address is :%@",address);
            self.addresslbl.text = address;


}];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

This is the moveable map code like ola and uber. Means when i move the map, at that time the map pin is noted, the noted pin  is given me address of the that particular area like city, state, pincode etc in label, but i want only the longitude, latitude value of this address in label.

so please help me about this code. How can i get the longitude latitude value in ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the label that you want to is `self.addresslbl`, change this method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude longitude:mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude];
    [self geocode:location];
}
```

To:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        self.addresslbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude, mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude];
    }
```

Comment: OK well if you could accept the answer that would be good. @NARAYAN